# find the average of hh:mm:ss in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with columns  script_name, start_time,end_time,duration. All the 3 columns are in the format of hh:mm:ss. I want to take the average value of these columns

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find the average of hh:mm:ss in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020821/how-to-find-the-average-of-hhmmss-in-hive)